# If value is X in table1 mark value X in table2

Tags: sql-server, key, rows

I'm trying to figure out how to make the following scenario work out in SQL Server:

We have two tables in a DB. Table1 contains full information of users with a column called "Tag" marked with values from 1 to 300.

We have another table which contains two columns where one is the number 1 to 300 as well and the second with either 0 or 1 as value.

We'd like that whenever a tag number is used in Table1 it marks it as "0" in Table2 standing for "in use" as 1 means "available".

Anyone who can assist me?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 as TABLE(
Tag  INT
)

DECLARE @tbl2 as TABLE(
Id  INT,
IsAvailable  BIT 
)

INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(5)

INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(1,NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(2,NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(3,NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(4,NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(5,NULL)

SELECT
    T1.Tag,
    T2.Id,  
    CASE ISNULL(T1.Tag,0) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsAvailable 
FROM @tbl2 T2
LEFT JOIN @tbl1 T1 ON T1.Tag=T2.Id
```